# C#- The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, rpt

I know this is asked question , however I have tried almost all the steps which was mentioned on stackoverflow or SAP.
I am using VS2015, on win 8(development) win 10(deployment).
I have installed nuget:
**crystalDecision and related references

Crystlreport.Reportappserver and related references**

Installed on development :

**CR13SP33MSI64_0-80007712.MSI

CRforVS13SP33_0-80007712.EXE

CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20

CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20**

On Deployment PC:
**CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_33.msi

CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_33.msi**

I tried Building using :
**Any CPU

X86

x64**

I can open RPT fle on IDE, but when I tried to run when build on `Any CPU` & x64,Error I am getting is :

[image]

When run via x86 it gives error runtime:

[image]

Please help

Comment: Need to know what the actual exception is - can you dump out `Exception.Message` and (if not null) `Exception.InnerException.Message` ?

Comment: can you guide me , how to do it ?